# Drawing a Rectangle with Certain Parameters

Tags: vb.net, graphics, drawing

I have an application that draws a rectangle  as a region then once the mouse clicks outside of the region it exits the program. Rather than hard coding coordinates into the rectangle is there a way to make it automatically draw to a window size of the program?

For example if you have a "Restored Down" window and run the program once you click outside that restored down window it will automatically exit the program.

I know this isn't the best description and I don't have any source code I'm just wondering if this is possible I guess.

Comment: Can you describe in more detail?...or perhaps make some photo mock-ups?

Comment: idle_mind is right. Your question is poorly explained and thus I will better delete the answer I wrote. Please, clarify exactly what you are looking for and I might un-delete my answer (and, eventually, improve it).